# How to include the contents of another cell within an excel formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to include the contents of one cell into a formula such as:

```
='Sheet 1'!G[R1]
```

`R1` is just a number referencing a chosen cell I need in Sheet 1
The code that produces this number is:

```
=IF(AND(Q7="Not Void", F7='Sheet 1'!A:A), "No Record", MATCH(F7,'Sheet 1'!A:A,0))
```

I'm stuck at combining the cell contents of `R1` with the query... is there a way to do this? and even better combine the previous query as well?

Many Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you getting at an INDEX/MATCH?

Comment: @BigBen Yes this produces a number for example 1652

Comment: `=IF(AND(Q7="Not Void", F7='Sheet 1'!A:A), "No Record", INDEX('Sheet1'!G:G,MATCH(F7,'Sheet 1'!A:A,0)))`?

Comment: Or maybe you're looking for `INDEX('Sheet1'!G:G,R1)`.